# Add namespace prefix in every element in SOAP response

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, websphere-9

I'm creating a web service where the client that is calling my service expects namespace prefix in every element in the SOAP response.

In simple example, the client want response like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <dlwmin:GetEmployeesByDeptResponse xmlns:dlwmin="http://tempuri.org/" 
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <dlwmin:EmployeesListResult>
            <dlwmin:Employee>
               <dlwmin:firstName>John</dlwmin:firstName>
               <dlwmin:lastName>Doe</dlwmin:lastName>
            </dlwmin:Employee>
            <dlwmin:Employee>
               <dlwmin:firstName>Audrey</dlwmin:firstName>
               <dlwmin:lastName>Gibson</dlwmin:lastName>
            </dlwmin:Employee>
         </dlwmin:EmployeesListResult>
      </dlwmin:GetEmployeesByDeptResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But my current response is:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <dlwmin:GetEmployeesByDeptResponse xmlns:dlwmin="http://tempuri.org/" 
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <EmployeesListResult>
            <Employee>
               <firstName>John</firstName>
               <lastName>Doe</lastName>
            </Employee>
            <Employee>
               <firstName>Audrey</firstName>
               <lastName>Gibson</lastName>
            </Employee>
         </EmployeesListResult>
      </dlwmin:GetEmployeesByDeptResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My SOAP Service (JAX-WS) is Deployed on the WebSphere Application Server 9.0 Network Deployment (FixPack 5) and the source code in shown bellow:

**Project Structure**

[image]

**EmployeesSearch.java**

```
package com.pp.endpoints;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;
import javax.xml.ws.BindingType;
import javax.xml.ws.RequestWrapper;
import javax.xml.ws.ResponseWrapper;

import com.pp.entities.Employee;
import com.pp.entities.Employees;

@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", name = "EmployeesSearch", 
            portName = "EmployeesSearchPort", serviceName = "EmployeesSearchService", 
            wsdlLocation = "WEB-INF/wsdl/EmployeesSearchService.wsdl")
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT)
@BindingType(javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
public class EmployeesSearch {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "GetEmployeesByDeparetment", action = "GetEmployeesByDeparetment")
    @WebResult(name = "EmployeesListResult")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "GetEmployeesByDeptRequest", className = "GetEmployeesByDeptRequest")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "GetEmployeesByDeptResponse", className = "GetEmployeesByDeptResponse")
    public Employees getEmployeesByDeparetment(@WebParam(name = "department") String department) {

        Employees employess = new Employees();

        if (department.equals("dev")) {
            Employee emp1 = new Employee("John", "Doe");
            employess.getEmpList().add(emp1);

            Employee emp2 = new Employee("Audrey", "Gibson");
            employess.getEmpList().add(emp2);
        } else if(department.equals("QA")) {
            Employee emp1 = new Employee("Sylvia", "Vinson");
            employess.getEmpList().add(emp1);

            Employee emp2 = new Employee("Zelenia", "Stark");
            employess.getEmpList().add(emp2);
        }

        return employess;
    }
}
```

**GetEmployeesByDeptRequest.java**

```
package com.pp.endpoints;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "department" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "GetEmployeesByDeptRequest")
public class GetEmployeesByDeptRequest implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6866935846016764952L;

    protected String department;

    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

}
```

**GetEmployeesByDeptResponse.java**

```
package com.pp.endpoints;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

import com.pp.entities.Employee;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "employeesListResult" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "GetEmployeesByDeptResponse")
public class GetEmployeesByDeptResponse implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3929452574007113319L;

    @XmlElement(name = "EmployeesListResult")
    protected Employee employeesListResult;

    public Employee getEmployeesListResult() {
        return employeesListResult;
    }

    public void setEmployeesListResult(Employee employeesListResult) {
        this.employeesListResult = employeesListResult;
    }
}
```

**package-info.java**

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://tempuri.org/", 
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.pp.endpoints;
```

**Employee.java**

```
package com.pp.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Employee", propOrder = { "firstName", "lastName" })
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1382336004216274895L;

    @XmlElement(name = "firstName")
    protected String firstName;

    @XmlElement(name = "lastName")
    protected String lastName;

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

**Employees.java**

```
package com.pp.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Employees", propOrder = { "empList" })
public class Employees implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6738577250797101596L;

    @XmlElement(name = "Employee", nillable = true)
    protected List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Employees() { }

    public List<Employee> getEmpList() {
        if (empList == null) {
            empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        }

        return empList;
    }

    public void setEmpList(List<Employee> empList) {
        this.empList = empList;
    }
}
```

**Question:** What should I change in the source code in order to get response where every element has a namespace prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Please use HeaderHandler class and add this 
 **this.addToHeader(envelope, header, "dlwmin", "your endpoint");**

```
 List<Handler> handlerChain = new ArrayList<Handler>();
          HeaderHandler hh = new HeaderHandler();
          handlerChain.add(hh);
          return handlerChain;
```

excample:[HeaderHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459859/java-web-service-soap-how-do-i-add-a-soap-handler-on-the-client-side-and-e)

```
public class HeaderHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {


    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext smc)throws Fault {






        Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean) smc.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);


        if (outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {


            SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage();



            try {

                if(App.sid!=null){

                               message.setProperty("sid", App.sid);

                }

                SOAPEnvelope envelope = smc.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();               

                SOAPHeader header = envelope.addHeader();



                this.addToHeader(envelope, header, "To", "https://wyszukiwarkaregontest.stat.gov.pl/wsBIR/UslugaBIRzewnPubl.svc");



                if(App.jakiNaglowek==1){

                                this.addToHeader(envelope, header, "Action", "http://CIS/BIR/PUBL/2014/07/IUslugaBIRzewnPubl/Zaloguj");



                }

                if(App.jakiNaglowek==2){

                this.addToHeader(envelope, header, "Action", "http://CIS/BIR/PUBL/2014/07/IUslugaBIRzewnPubl/Wyloguj");



               }

                if(App.jakiNaglowek==3){

                                this.addToHeader(envelope, header, "Action", "http://CIS/BIR/2014/07/IUslugaBIR/SetValue");



                  }

                if(App.jakiNaglowek==4){

                                this.addToHeader(envelope, header, "Action", "http://CIS/BIR/2014/07/IUslugaBIR/GetValue");



                 }

                if(App.jakiNaglowek==5){

                                this.addToHeader(envelope, header, "Action", "http://CIS/BIR/PUBL/2014/07/IUslugaBIRzewnPubl/DaneKomunikat");



                }



                               if(App.jakiNaglowek==7){

                                this.addToHeader(envelope, header, "Action", "http://CIS/BIR/PUBL/2014/07/IUslugaBIRzewnPubl/DanePobierzPelnyRaport");



                   }

                if(App.jakiNaglowek==6){

                this.addToHeader(envelope, header, "Action", "http://CIS/BIR/2014/07/IUslugaBIR/PobierzCaptcha");





               }

//                if(App.jakiNaglowek==7){

//                            this.addToHeader(envelope, header, "Action", "http://CIS/BIR/PUBL/2014/07/IUslugaBIRzewnPubl/DaneKomunikat");

//               

//                           //

//                }



                if(App.jakiNaglowek==9){

                                this.addToHeader(envelope, header, "Action", "http://CIS/BIR/2014/07/IUslugaBIR/SprawdzCaptcha");





                  }

                if(App.jakiNaglowek==10){

                                this.addToHeader(envelope, header, "Action", "http://CIS/BIR/PUBL/2014/07/IUslugaBIRzewnPubl/DaneSzukaj");





                 }

               //  Header headTo = new Header(new QName("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing", "To", "wsa"), wsaTo, new JAXBDataBinding(String.class));







               // SOAPElement security =

                    //    header.addChildElement("Security", "wsse", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");


                //SOAPElement usernameToken =

                 //       security.addChildElement("UsernameToken", "wsse");

               // usernameToken.addAttribute(new QName("xmlns:wsu"), "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");


              //  SOAPElement username =

               //         usernameToken.addChildElement("Username", "wsse");

               // username.addTextNode("");


              //  SOAPElement password =

               //         usernameToken.addChildElement("Password", "wsse");

              //  password.setAttribute("Type", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText");

              //  password.addTextNode("");


                //Print out the outbound SOAP message to System.out

                message.writeTo(System.out);

                System.out.println("");



            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }


        } else {

            try {



                //This handler does nothing with the response from the Web Service so

                //we just print out the SOAP message.

                SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage();



                message.writeTo(System.out);

                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                message.writeTo(stream);

                String response = new String(stream.toByteArray(), "utf-8");



                System.out.println("");

                //System.out.println("Dodatkowy wydruk");

               // System.out.println("Dziwne "+response);

               // System.out.println("KONIEC");





            } catch (Exception ex) {

                ex.printStackTrace();

            }

        }




        return outboundProperty;


    }


    public Set getHeaders() {

                Set<QName> set = new HashSet<QName>();

        // Make sure the '[{http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}]Action' header

        // is handled in case the device set the 'MustUnderstand' attribute to '1'

        set.add(new QName("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing", "Action"));

        return set;

    }


    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {

        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");

                System.out.println("Inside handle fault:: " + context);



        return true;

    }


    public void close(MessageContext context) {

    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");

    }



    private void addToHeader(SOAPEnvelope envelope, SOAPHeader header, String key, String value) throws SOAPException {

        Name qname = envelope.createName(key, "wsa", "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing");

        SOAPHeaderElement element = header.addHeaderElement(qname);

        element.addTextNode(value);



    }

}
```